# Removing the duplicate object in Array in javascript by comparing with key of the object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Array I want to remove duplicate object example bison is coming 2 times.

```
var beasts = [ {'ant':false}, {'bison':true}, {'camel':true}, {'duck':false}, {'bison':false} ];
```

This is what I tried

```
let a =  beasts.indexOf(bison);
console.log(a);
```

But all the time it give -1 that means the object is not there at all

please ignore the values of the object

Comment: There are 2 objects with `bison` having values, true and false. Which object you need to keep?

Comment: I just want to remove any of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Maintain a **set** of **unique keys** and if the value exists in the set, return `false` else add it to set and return `true`.

```js
var beasts = [ {'ant':false}, {'bison':true}, {'camel':true}, {'duck':false}, {'bison':false} ];
let set = new Set();
let result = beasts.filter(o => {
  // Get the key of object 
  let key = Object.keys(o)[0];
  if(!set.has(key)) { // check for existence in set
    // if does not exist add it to set and return true (filter IN)
    set.add(key);
    return true;
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks you very much

Comment: @nitish - Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way

```
const beasts = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'John'];

let beasts = [...new Set(names)];
console.log(unique); // 'John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo'
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this programmatically, maintain a separate array that will hold names of processed beasts and then reduce the original array in relation to processedBeastsArray;

```
var beasts = [ {'ant':false}, {'bison':true}, {'camel':true}, {'duck':false}, {'bison':false} ];

const processedBeasts = [];
const result = beasts.reduce(function(final, current) {
  const currentBeastName = Object.keys(current)[0];
  if(!processedBeasts.includes(currentBeastName)){
    processedBeasts.push(currentBeastName);
    final.push(current);
  }
  return final;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple `forEach()` loop that has `O(n)` complexity to get that output.

```js
var beasts = [ {'ant':false}, {'bison':true}, {'camel':true}, {'duck':false}, {'bison':false} ];
var resObj = {};
beasts.forEach((beast)=>{
  var key = Object.keys(beast)[0];
  if(!resObj[key]){
    resObj[key] = beast;
  }
});
var finalArrayRes = Object.values(resObj);
console.log(finalArrayRes);
```